# How to make ginput confine to current axes for selecting a seed point

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, ginput

I am attaching a sample GUI codes, which has two axes with 2 images and when I use ginput to select seed point I am able to select on either axes, Is there anyway to limit the ginput to a specific axes

```
% --- Executes on button press in open.
function open_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to open (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global img1;
global img2;

img1 = imread('peppers.png');
img2 = imread('rice.png');

axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(img1,[]);
axes(handles.axes2);
imshow(img2,[]);


% --- Executes on button press in seedpointSelect.
function seedpointSelect_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to seedpointSelect (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global img1;
global img2;
global x;
global y;

axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(img1,[]);
[y,x] = ginput(handles.axes1);
y = round(y); x = round(x);
set(handles.xcord,'String',num2str(x));
set(handles.ycord,'String',num2str(y));
```

Any help on limiting ginput to a specific axes,

Thanks,
Gopi

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of MATLAB you used to be able to change the `HitTest` property of the `axes` to ignore the click from `ginput`

```
set(handles.axes2, 'Hittest', 'off')
```

The better approach though is to use `ButtonDownFcn` as you have much more control over mouse events with an `axes` object.

From within your `OpeningFcn`

```
set(handles.axes1, 'ButtonDownFcn', @mouseCallback)
```

Then you'll need to create the callback function

```
function mouseCallback(src, evnt)
    handles = guidata(src);

    % Get the current point
    xyz = get(src, 'CurrentPoint');

    x = xyz(1,1);
    y = xyz(1,2);

    % Store x/y here or whatever you need to do
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ginput`, create a mouse click callback instead (`ButtonDownFcn`). You can set the callback to, for example, remove the callback function from the axis. In your main program, which sets the callback, you then `waitfor` that property to change. As soon as the user clicks, you get control back, and you can then read the location of the last mouse click (`CurrentPoint`). Note that the position you read out is in axis coordinates, not screen pixels. This is a good thing, it most likely corresponds to a pixel in the image displayed.